# ??? is displayed instead of € when MVC Grid.net first loads

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, mvcgrid.net

I'm using MVC Grid.Net for a grid that shows prices in one of it's columns. When the grid first loads ??? is displayed instead of €.

Inside my AddCols method I have the code

```
cols.Add()
    .WithColumnName("Rent Amount")
    .WithValueExpression(x => "€" + x.AnnualRent.Amount.ToString(Resource.CurrencyFormat));
```

I have also tried

```
cols.Add()
    .WithColumnName("Rent Amount")
    .WithValueExpression(x => x.AnnualRent.Amount.ToString("C"));
```

Once I interact with the grid like sorting a column the currency symbol displays correctly.

I'm not sure what is causing this.

Thanks for any help

Comment: what is your culture setup as on your machine..?

Comment: my culture is set to en-ie. The application will only be used for an Irish market. For kicks I tried £ and $, they both work fine

Comment: This question displays 3 white-on-black question marks if I manually set Text Encoding to ISO-2022-JP. Can you rule out the behavior is caused by the browser?

Comment: other areas where I use € in the app works fine outside the grid. I fixed this issue by updating the MVCGrid.Net package to the latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by a simple update of the nuget package. I had 1.0.0.57 and upgrading to 1.0.0.60 fixed the issue